# How can I access the class from the other javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing the web application with webpack. I have two javascript files.

**app.js**

```
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  say() {
    return 'My name is ' + this._name;
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import app from './app.js';
let user = new app.User('Alice');
console.log(user.say());
```

I'd like to print "My name is Alice" on the console, but it doesn't work. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to export the class in app.js and import it in main.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the class from app.js and then import it in main.js:

```
// app.js
export default class User {
   constructor(name) {
      this._name = name;
   }

   say() {
      return 'My name is ' + this._name;
   }
}
```

Import User class from app.js:

```
// main.js
import User from './app';

let user = new User('Alice');
console.log(user.say());
```

Comment: As a side-note, I'll mention that the import of the default does not need to use the same name `User` as the export, `import foo from './app'` is equivalent to `import {default as foo} from './app'`, although it is better to retain the name.

Comment: Thank you Dan Weber. and @AndyG too!

Answer (score 0):

add `export default User` as the last line. This will export the class user as default. which means you can access it in main.js with a name of your choice as you have done above. If you export it as `export User`, when you import it in the main.js file you will have to import it as User itself.

Or you can export it in the first line itself like `export default class User {`